# QLCDNumber updating with processEvents() - Python 3

Tags: python, qt, pyside

G'day,

I'm trying to include an LCD countdown timer in my software. Here's what I currently have, with an attempt at using processEvents().

```
n = 6
while n > -1:
    self.LCDTransactionCountdown.display(n)
    QtCore.QCoreApplication.processEvents()
    n = n - 1
    time.sleep(1)
print("Session expired.")
```

I've read about this topic elsewhere, and I found that the time.sleep() command is not suitable for this task? When I run the above code, the LCD will display a countdown of sorts, but it will pause slightly too long on one number, and then skip the following number. I added a print(n) line to the while loop to check whether the loop was running as planned, and it was.

I've read that QTimer would be more suitable for this task, but for the life of me I cannot understand the documentation for PySide. I've read through the documentation on QTimer, but I don't understand why I need to use SIGNALS and SLOTS for this purpose?

Hopefully I've missed something really simple here. I have a feeling I'm not using the processEvents() handler correctly...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This page](http://ralsina.me/weblog/posts/BB974.html) has some info, but I'll summarize what might be helpful to you here. It looks like the issue that you might be having with sleep stems from the fact that execution may not resume as soon as the program is done sleeping if the system is busy when that happens.

The following function establishes a QTimer to fire function f every second.

```
QTimer.singleShot(1000, f)
```

Using that in your while loop to fire off `QtCore.QCoreApplication.processEvents()` might solve your problem. One thing to note with this is that it won't fire ever until after the first second is up. To fire the method the first time, use `QTimer.singleShot(0, f)`.

Another method would be the second manner to run the timer as listed at the source link.

```
timer = QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.processEvents()) #This gets run every timer cycle
timer.start(1000)
```

It appears that this method and the `singleshot()` method are similar, but I posted both in the event that the first didn't work properly.

If you are still having issues, try doing something like this

```
def myFunction():
   try:
       QtCore.QCoreApplication.processEvents()
   finally:
       QTimer.singleShot(1000, myFunction())
```

This will cause processEvents to fire and then queue for every second after. Since it's in a finally statment, it will fire again even if processEvents breaks. The downside is that the 1 second wait time gets added onto the time that it takes processEvents() to run, which might not end the way you want it to.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply mate! Your post made me understand the QTimer class much better, so thank you for that. I wish the PySide documentation was as straight forward...